# spring security context was not invalidated when server restart

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jboss7.x, remember-me

i am having peculiar issue with spring security context while my server restart happens, it is not invalidated , and this is still persisted during auto login.

Scenario 1 :-

> when user normally login (no autologin) then my
>   SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT is getting invalidated during my server
>   restart(JBOSS 7) or session timeout, and i am getting access
>   denied exception when user access any secured page during any of those
>   either restart or timeout happen, no issues here.

Scenario 2 :-

> when user checks remember me, and if he get autologged in, then i am
>   facing problem , where session is still persisted either for restart
>   or session timeout, in such case when user access any secure page he
>   was not thrown access denied exception, since his authentication
>   object persists in session, but other session stored datas are
>   invalidated.

this is really confusing me, only difference is autologin in Scenario 2, which is not invalidating session fully. help needed to fix this.

Comment: It is invalidating the session but due to the remember me will be logged in afterwards again. That is the whole purpose of remember me functionality.

Comment: @M.Deinum but i need to get the session invalidate including spring context when there is restart or session timeout..is there any solution to this?

Comment: The session is invalidated but the user just logs in again. Also if the session is destroyed or not depends, in the case of restarts, on the container. Tomcat serializes the session state before stopping and then reloading when starting again.

Comment: but this is not happening when user normally login without autologin.. i am fully surprised what difference does it makes?..so remember me is storing session in server and recovers on restart?

Comment: The session will be invalidated BUT due to the remember-me functionality he will login automatically as soon as a valid security context is not found. That is the whole point of the remember me functionality!!!